# Despawning problem in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why do my animals keep despawning?
I went to chop down some trees and organise my storage system. When I returned to see my animals, they were mostly gone. I don't know about Villagers if this was the same or if a Zombie horde attacked them. It may be my low-end tablet (I'm on Pocket Edition). My render distance is 4 chunks.

Comment: What mobs are your animals? As far as I know, only hostile (enemy) mobs can despawn. If your animals are gone, they either moved away or somehow got killed.

Comment: You can uses name tag to stop them from despawning

Answer (score 2):

Most mobs will despawn unless any of the following are true:

- Cannot Move 20 blocks in any direction
- Are named with a name tag
- Are saddled/tamed
- Are on a lead connected to a fence
- Are a special mob (i.e. Iron Golem, Wither, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Animals can't despwan if they are unable to move 20 blocks in any direction so it might be that they have too much space and are despawning because of it.